# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo java.lang.IllegalStateException:Fragment not attached to Activity

Tags: android-fragments

I'm working with a fragment but its always throwing the error that it cannot start the activity because the fragmentis not attached to the activity,
kindly assist me figure out where I'm messing
Below is my code for the Fragment and Activity:

Fragment

```
package com.sarham.kabs.fruity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

import adapters.CategoriesListAdapter;

/**
 * Created by Kabunyi Wanja on 22/03/2015.
 */
public class CategoriesFragment extends ListFragment {
    private ListView categoriesListView;
    private String[] categoriesArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer_list);

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.categories_fragment, container, false);
        categoriesListView = (ListView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        //setCategoriesListAdapter();
        //Log.d("ADAPTER: ", "Adapter has been set for listview");

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setCategoriesListAdapter();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    //set adapter to categoriesListView
    public void setCategoriesListAdapter(){
        categoriesListView.setAdapter(new CategoriesListAdapter(getActivity(), categoriesArray));
    }
}
```

Activity

```
package com.sarham.kabs.fruity;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ListView listView;
    private String[] planets;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.drawerListView);
        planets = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets);
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, planets));
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        drawerListener = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close){
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Drawer Open", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Drawer Closed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerListener);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        CategoriesFragment categories = new CategoriesFragment();
        addFragment(R.id.drawerLayout, categories, "CATEGORIES");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        drawerListener.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        drawerListener.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        if(drawerListener.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(this, planets[position]+" Was selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        selectItem(position);

        switch (position){
            case 0:
                CategoriesFragment categories = new CategoriesFragment();
                addFragment(R.id.drawerLayout, categories, "CATEGORIES");

                break;
            case 1:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Settings was selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                break;
            case 2:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Exit was selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();

                break;
            default:
        }
    }
    public void selectItem(int position){
        listView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(planets[position]);
    }
    //set ActionBar title
    public void setTitle(String title){
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
    //call this method to add a fragment
    public void addFragment(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag){
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(containerViewId, fragment, tag);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Below is the LogCat ouput:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment CategoriesFragment{41545e80} not attached to Activity
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:619)
            at com.sarham.kabs.fruity.CategoriesFragment.<init>(CategoriesFragment.java:21)
            at com.sarham.kabs.fruity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:55)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5020)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post the logcat error messages pls.

Answer (score 0):

On carefull analysis of the Fragment lifecycle, Its not possible to carry out operations like fetching of string resources using the getResources().getStringArray(...) as I was doing, this has to be done within the method onActivityCreated(...)